# How to test dir creation errors in php (windows)

Tags: php, windows, phpunit

I have very short piece of code, but I cannot find the correct way how to test it using eg. PHPUnit. Of course testing it in Linux is easier I think because of permissions over files but what I can do the test under Windows file system? Here is the code:

```
private function createCacheDir(string $cacheDir): void
{
    if (!is_dir($cacheDir)) {
        if (!mkdir($cacheDir, 0755, true)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Dir %s cannot be created.', $cacheDir));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that such folder does not exists it is simply created and I do not know how to make second if falsy. I will be happy for any working solution.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the path.

Comment: Use [bovigo/vfsStream](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream) instead of testing on an unknown live filesystem.

Comment: I know this will not help much, but I would just recommend to try start using Laravel. I am not sure if you are using a framework or not, but nowadays, not using Laravel or Symfony for any PHP app is just opening the doors to hell 

Comment: I think that not happy was the name of method `createCacheDir`. If I gave the name `createDir` suggestions of use framework will not appear... :( But problem is the same, how to test correctness of creating dir.

Comment: @AlexHowansky has right. I will use such solution. Thanks! You can simply write the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) said the most sensible answer is to use [bovigo/vfsStream](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream) eg.:

```
public function setUp(): void
{        
    $this->baseCacheDir = vfsStream::setup('baseCacheDir');
}    

public function testConstructorIfNotWritableDir(): void
{
    $baseCacheDir = vfsStream::url('baseCacheDir');
    $this->baseCacheDir->chmod(0444);
    $cacheDir = $baseCacheDir.'/cacheDir';
    $this->expectException(\RuntimeException::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage(sprintf('Dir %s cannot be created.', $cacheDir));
    $this->getObjectUnderTest($cacheDir);//Here is created Object under test and is executed this private method from the question.
}
```